# Dynamic data scaffolding of ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, scaffolding, asp.net-dynamic-data

I am thinking to use Dynamic data scaffolding of ASP.net

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee377606.aspx

is this a good idea for best speed of data query in the app.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic data doesn't really have anything to do with the performance of data access. It's designed to provide a Web UI with little or no code. The "scaffolding" refers to the automatic generation of web pages to manage data.

From the link in your question:

> *Scaffolding* refers to the Dynamic Data elements that automatically
>   generate Web pages for each table in a database.